# Serving css, js files in Node.js without frameworks like Express

Tags: node.js

This question has probably been asked earlier but the answers are not very convincing.
I have the following code with me -

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs');                                 
connect = require('connect');    

function serveStaticFile(res, path, contentType, responseCode) {
    if(!responseCode) responseCode = 200;
    fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(err,data) {
            if(err) {
                    res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
                    res.end('500 - Internal Error');
            } else {
                    res.writeHeader(responseCode,
                            { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                    res.write(data)
                    res.end();
            }
    });
}

http.createServer(function(req,res){
    // normalize url by removing querystring, optional
    // trailing slash, and making lowercase
    var path = req.url.replace(/\/?(?:\?.*)?$/, '')
            .toLowerCase();
    switch(path) {
            case '': serveStaticFile(res, '/public/index.html','texthtml');
                    break;
            default:
                    serveStaticFile(res, '/public/404.html', 'text/html',
                            404);
                    break;
    }
 }).listen(3000);

console.log('Server started on localhost:3000; press Ctrl-C to terminate....');
```

I am just not able to load the css and js files mentioned in the index.js. What am I doing wrong? If I open index.js in the browser directly, the css and js load fine.

Comment: Well your switch statement seems to always serve the 404 page if `path` is not `''`. Maybe that's' the problem?

Comment: no, thats not the problem...when I simply give localhost:3000, it does display the index.html but there's no css or js loaded.

Comment: Yes, but your browser is making separate requests for the css and js, but it just gets 404 for them because of that switch statement.

Comment: true, which is what I want to prevent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express uses [serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static) for serving static directories which is uses [send](https://www.npmjs.com/package/send) for streaming files. You can use that instead of express, or take at a look their implementation.

Comment: Sure. Let me take a look!

Comment: Ended up using serve-static

Answer (score 1):

What are you think about `send` ? Use that like this:

```
function serveStaticFile(res, path, contentType, responseCode) {
    if(!responseCode) responseCode = 200;
    res.status = responseCode;

    function error(err) {
        res.statusCode = err.status || 500;
        res.end(err.message);
    }

    function headers(res, path, stat) {
        res.setHeader('Content-type', contentType);
    }

      send(req, path, {root: __dirname})
      .on('error', error)
      .on('headers', headers)
      .pipe(res);
}
```